# Reuse/recharge of a LiPo cell phone battery

Tags: lipo

I am making major upgrades to a Bluetooth stereo I have and as a result require a stronger battery than the original. I happened to have a much larger LiPo battery from an old cell phone sitting around which was also 3.7V

The cell phone battery has 3 pins, positive (labeled), negative(labeled), and a third pin I read was for communication with the phone.

Currently the circuit has a small chip which I believe is for regulating when the battery is done charging. Am I correct about this chip plus internal safety measures of the battery? Allowing me to simply de-solder one battery & attach the larger one or will it over charge and set fire ?

[image: Small chip leading to current LiPo][image: Full Chip currently being upgraded]

Comment: What relevance are the pictures?

Comment: The third pin is often a thermistor connection for measuring the temperature during charge.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to, but probably not. Can you reverse engineer the circuit or at least identify the SOIC-8 in the upper right corner. That is probably the battery charger IC. Depends on the circuit and the new battery's specs though if it would work. You will also not be able to use the communication pin at all with a new battery so if the charging IC depends on reading data from that third pin you're probably at a dead end.

It would be best to just create your own charger rated for a bigger battery using off the shelf modules or components.

Answer (score 1):

It might work to put a somewhat larger battery on the same charger, due to the charge algorithm for lithium-ion or lithium-polymer being mostly to connect it to a voltage-limited and current-limited power source.  All else being equal, the larger battery would charge "slower" in the sense that current into the battery would be the same, but as a percentage of capacity it would be less, so the battery would take longer to get fully charged.  If you understood the charging circuit well enough to modify it for higher current you could possibly fix that.  This is assuming the battery is a single cell, which it appears to be in the photo (but may not be), so there isn't an issue with mismatch of voltage, cell balancing, etc.

Some pitfalls:

If the chemistry were a different variant of lithium-ion, the maximum charging voltage could be off by 0.1V or more, which could have a very detrimental effect on how many recharges the battery is good for, and potentially much worse problems, including fire.

The charger might have a timeout set to something a bit longer than it'd take a fully discharged battery to charge, so if the larger battery takes "too long" to charge then the timer might end charge before it gets full.  You'd only have to restart charge (like unplug & replug the wall adapter) to overcome that, but it might be a nuisance to do every time.

If your new battery were smaller, rather than larger (e.g. you replaced a failed battery with something from the drawer), the current might be set too high and hurt the battery.

As there are only two wires going from circuit board to battery in the original design, not a third wire for communication, it's likely the charger will treat any battery you attach to those wires the same it would treat the one the product shipped with.  If you could be sure the only difference between the original and larger battery was size/capacity (most especially: same chemistry), within some reasonable size difference it will probably be ok.

However, since you have no schematic, it's impossible to be sure things won't go really wrong.  To be safer you could measure or log the battery voltage & current as the original one charges to get a better idea of the charging current, maximum voltage, timeout if any, etc. and then buy a new larger battery which is compatible with that behavior.